# Ubuntu 64 bit server not working on Raspberry pi 4 -2GB

Tags: server, 64-bit, raspberrypi

Does anyone have a working solution for ubuntu 64 bit for raspberry pi 4 (2gb w 64gb sd card)?.
I know it's been an official release of ubuntu and it seems very strait forward according to instructions on the web page - it does however not work in practice for 64 bit version.h

File used as recommended from ubuntu web page: "ubuntu-19.10.1-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img"

When I boot it quickly jumps the login section and gets stuck on
"[ OK ] Reached target Cloud-init target"

I've made multiple tries and also added
total_mem=2048 in usercfg.txt file after the flash. When this is done, the boot goes a bit further and gets stuck at another position:
"[ OK ] Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities"

Any workaround available?

Comment: Did you verify your image post-download?  For other architectures I'd also suggest verifying your write to install media; but I don't know if that options exists for your architecture.

Comment: I did not verify the image. I'm not quite sure how to do it on windows (used to prepare the card and files) but I will try.

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 maybe helpful but it'll likely assume a different architecture. You can also use a `sha256sum`, or `md5sum` or like tool (maybe https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=11533 or equivalent for your system)

Comment: I ran the following:
CertUtil -hashfile ubuntu-19.10.1-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img SHA256
SHA256 hash of ubuntu-19.10.1-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img:
24b184762a2ebdca0e7f8151d3ea84e82c5e0c4a7f5a85f24f12f1cd5b197560
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.

This is what I understand that I should receive from the web page:3fcae7490edebd35663cb30dcd7a6317b6b9601d0f59ed5caa3c20dfd936cbb1 *ubuntu-19.10.1-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/19.10.1/release/SHA256SUMS?_ga=2.258687618.90238011.1578237178-1788020754.1578237178

Comment: As those numbers are not the same it means the download was corrupt?

Comment: If the numbers don't match perfectly; YES normally it does mean the download was flawed & thus it won't work.  If there is a minor glitch (minor bits different) the shasum results will be very different, if almost the same the files are very very different (usually different size, or easily spotted).  I'm aware of windows users have problems before because some tools on windows give wrong results (the same program has to be used both ends as non-standard checksums are used) but I don't know.  I'd test downloading another small file where you can compare hash with a known value (non-msft hash)

Comment: Thank you guiverc! Do you have any chance to try to download the iso file for 64 bit from "https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi" and see if you get it right?

I also cannot find that release under official releases: http://releases.ubuntu.com/19.10/

Comment: I've tried to download again and i get the following SHA256 verification number once more: 24b184762a2ebdca0e7f8151d3ea84e82c5e0c4a7f5a85f24f12f1cd5b197560 while according to web page it says it should be: 3fcae7490edebd35663cb30dcd7a6317b6b9601d0f59ed5caa3c20dfd936cbb1 .... not quite sure what to do now?

Comment: I'd have downloaded using a different box (to ensure a browser extension isn't modifying during download/save mitm style), ideally on a different network (again mitm mitigation) and if you got the same checksum - it's more likely your checksum program isn't POSIX compliant thus the different results  (windows can add a ^Z/EOF character; if added by windows it should be ignored but I'm aware some windows apps have historically counted that too; checksum methods are older than windows).   I'd then try and write image to different card using different tool/box - if same result ... *your question*

Comment: Thank you guiverc. I will now be gone for a few days but will try your advice as soon as I return.